# How to send the value what I want in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a question about how to send the value from Controller to View.

I try to make a code like this :

```
public JsonResult GetAllProductPrice(string ID)
{
    var OrderDetailsListModel = OrderDetailsListRe.Get(
        n => n.OrderDetailsSerial.Equals(ID) && n.Mode.Equals("1")).Select(n => new
        {
            ProSerial = n.ProSerial,
            ProName = n.ProName,
            Price = n.Price,
            Amount = n.Amount
        });

    return Json(OrderDetailsListModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

At View , I have complete a AJAX code to receive ProSerial,ProName,Price,Amount.

but if I want add a condition like that :

```
if (ProSerial.substring(0,2).equals("OD"))
{
    ViewBag.OD = "True";
}
else if (ProSerial.substring(0,3).equals("OC"))
{
    View.Bag.OD = "False";
}
```

I don't know how to add .... can somebody teach me ?

Comment: you try to get the data through jquery ajax or mvc? Viewbag only can be get trough MVC, so what you actually want? your jquery script and mvc html is needed to help you solve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access viewBag on the JS part. `ViewBag` as well as `ViewData` is used only for transfering data from `action of controller` to `view`. So I would recommend to make DTO(data transfer object) for this purpose:

```
public class AllProductPriceDTO
{
    public OrderDetailsListModel orderDetailsListModel {get;set;}
    public bool OD {get;set;}
}
```

so now you can return in your action of controller the AllProductPriceDTO instead of Model;

```
public JsonResult GetAllProductPrice(string ID)
{
    var OrderDetailsListModel = OrderDetailsListRe.Get(
        n => n.OrderDetailsSerial.Equals(ID) && n.Mode.Equals("1")).Select(n => new
        {
            ProSerial = n.ProSerial,
            ProName = n.ProName,
            Price = n.Price,
            Amount = n.Amount
        });
    var result = new OrderDetailsListModel(){orderDetailsListModel=OrderDetailsListModel};
    if(ProSerial.substring(0,2).equals("OD")){
       result.OD = true;
    }
    else if (ProSerial.substring(0,3).equals("OC"))
    {
       result.OD = false;
    }

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and now you can make ajax call and work with your `OD`:

```
$.get("/yourController/GetAllProductPrice", {}, function(result){console.log('EHHAY, OD is ->'+result.OD); console.log("OrderDetailsListModel ==>"+result.orderDetailsListModel);})
```

Comment: thank you very much , even I use jQuery to fix this question at front-end finally, but your answer is really really very cool !!